# array with a twist

Tags: amortized-analysis

Imagine that we have an array like structure A with n elements all of which are initially 0.
($A[i]=0$)

What is a data structure that supports the following operations:

1) Given an element A[i]=0 set A[i] to 1 in **O(1) worst case**

2) Given the index i return A[i] in **O(1) worst case**

3) Given the index i retrun the smallest $j\geq i$ such that $A[j]=0$ or $-1$ if there is no such index in **amortized time as small as possible**

Obviously an array supports the first 2. It doesnt not support 3). How to modify it?

Comment: Can you only set entries from 0 to 1 or can you also set entries from x to 0?

Comment: Only from 0 to 1

Comment: Yes, this is a nice homework exercise.  What have you tried?  What's the simplest technique you can think of to avoid repeating work?  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own before asking here, and to show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At every index of the array you should store an extra detail of the immediate index that contains a "0". Updating this index in an amortised complexity of O(1) will give the solution.

Suppose you are updating the extra detail at an index i and the immediate 0 is found at j. Then, the extra detail will have the value j for all the values between i & j.

Now the amortised cost for every operation will be O(1) for updating and retrieving the stored index is O(1).